# parsing different javascript from same source

Tags: javascript

i know these things can be done easily through php but in shopify store i saw javascript attached like this async.

```
https:\/\/sometime.com\/shopify\/script.js?shop=storename1.myshopify.com
https:\/\/sometime.com\/shopify\/script.js?shop=storename2.myshopify.com
https:\/\/sometime.com\/shopify\/script.js?shop=storename3.myshopify.com
```

and to my surprize all three code was different.

anyone can tell what is happening behind the scene. how it is possible that different javascript is passes from same script.js ??

any help will be great learning

Comment: `script.js` is being routed to a script that checks the URL parameter and returns different JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

`https:\/\/sometime.com\/shopify\/script.js`

is essentially not like there is a file `script.js` inside directory `/shopify`, rather it is a route. And then the `shop` acts here as a query parameter for GET request, the server reads it and returns the response accordingly.

Comment: can u plz explain little more. i have seen this sort of thing first time through js so detail explaination will be helpful. routing through php or how exactly

Comment: Go through this URL, though server based routing can be done in multiple ways, based on language and server, read this Node JS Express server. https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html